# VBA convert DAO connection string and Recordset to ODBC

Tags: vba, ms-word, odbc

I have an add-in that's written in VBA in Word that is rather old. I think it dates back to 1997. Currently the VBA code will connect to an Access 2003 database and query a table and return a recordset of the data and generate a list of vendors from that table query.

Below is the code that uses the DAO method. The problem now is the newer computers that we are receiving that have windows 10 do not have the older libraries that the DAO method works with. (Plus DAO itself is old and outdated).

```
Public strData() As String

Sub GetData(strTable As String)
Dim dbf As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Counter As Long
Dim strCriteria As String


If strTable = "VendorQ" Then
    strCriteria = "SELECT NameSort FROM Vendor Where Qualified = -1 ORDER BY NameSort"
ElseIf strTable = "VendorU" Then
    strCriteria = "SELECT NameSort FROM Vendor Where Qualified = 0 ORDER BY NameSort"
ElseIf strTable = "MainR" Then
    strCriteria = "SELECT NameSort FROM Vendor ORDER BY NameSort"
Else
    MsgBox "Error"
End If

Set dbf = OpenDatabase("\\fileLocation\center.mdb")
Set rst = dbf.OpenRecordset(strCriteria)

frmCenter.MousePointer = fmMousePointerHourGlass
Counter = 0
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rst.MoveLast

    ReDim strData(rst.RecordCount - 1) As String
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst.EOF
        strData(Counter) = rst![NameSort]
        Counter = Counter + 1
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    ReDim strData(0)
End If
frmCenter.MousePointer = fmMousePointerArrow
rst.Close
End Sub
```

This will return a list:

[image]

The table already exists in a MySQL database so I could use an ODBC connection to retrieve the data and not mess with Access as a pass thru to a linked table. I tried converting the connection string and it connects to the database but for some reason doesn't show the list of vendors.

Here is the converted code:

```
Public strData() As String

Sub GetData(strTable As String)
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Counter As Long
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

Set remoteCon = New ADODB.Connection

conStr = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;" & _
    "UID=uid;PWD=pwd"
    
remoteCon.ConnectionString = conStr
remoteCon.Open

remoteCon.Execute ("USE database;")

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

If strTable = "VendorQ" Then
    strCriteria = "SELECT NameSort FROM Vendor Where Qualified = -1 ORDER BY NameSort"
ElseIf strTable = "VendorU" Then
    strCriteria = "SELECT NameSort FROM Vendor Where Qualified = 0 ORDER BY NameSort"
ElseIf strTable = "MainR" Then
    strCriteria = "SELECT NameSort FROM Main ORDER BY NameSort"
Else
    MsgBox "Error"
End If

With rst
    .ActiveConnection = remoteCon
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Source = strCriteria
    .Open
End With

frmCenter.MousePointer = fmMousePointerHourGlass
Counter = 0
If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rst.MoveLast

    ReDim strData(rst.RecordCount - 1) As String
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst.EOF
        strData(Counter) = rst![NameSort]
        Counter = Counter + 1
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    ReDim strData(0)
End If
frmCenter.MousePointer = fmMousePointerArrow
rst.Close
End Sub
```

[image]

Is there a different way to populate the recordset from an ODBC source?

Comment: I’d swap out `If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then` for a check on `rst.EOF`.  Recordcount isn’t very reliable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this answer by Erik A https://stackoverflow.com/a/46130089/2359206
Adding .CursorLocation = adUseClient to the rst open string solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`RecordCount` is often unreliable until after you've run to the end of the recordset (as in MoveLast for example) so I'd use a check on EOF instead:

```vb
If Not rst.EOF Then
    rst.MoveLast
    ReDim strData(rst.RecordCount - 1) As String
    rst.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst.EOF
        strData(Counter) = rst![NameSort]
        Counter = Counter + 1
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    ReDim strData(0)
End If
```

EDIT:

FYI in my tests RecordCount was always -1 using `adOpenDynamic` but I got the correct value with `adOpenKeyset`

If `RecordCount` is not reliable then you can use `GetRows()` to transfer the records to a 2D array, then use that to resize and populate `strData`

```vb
If Not rs.EOF Then
    arrRecs = rs.GetRows 'a 2D array (0 to #cols-1, 0 to #rows-1)
    ReDim strData(UBound(arrRecs, 2))
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrRecs, 2)
        strData(i) = arrRecs(0, i)
    Next i
Else
    ReDim strData(0)
End If
```

Comment: I receive a `subscript out of range` on the `strData(Counter) = rst![NameSort]`  line when it moves to the second record. I put a watch on the `rst` and it seems like some of the flags aren't being set. For example, when it does `rst.MoveLast` the `rst.EOF` still shows false.

Comment: What is the value of `RecordCount` after the `MoveLast` ?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I made a mistake. RecordCount is always -1 but if I look at the Fields property and then Fields.Count is 1 on MoveLast

Comment: You will always have fields even if there are no records...  Find out *which* subscript is out of range

Comment: So I tried two different things. I tried the original `ReDim strData(rst.RecordCount - 1) As String` line and I get the subscript out of range on that line. RecordCount is always -1.
Secondly, I tried setting the rst.RecordCount as rst.Fields.Count and I get the subscript out of range on the `strData(Counter) = rst![NameSort]` when the Counter variable is 2.
The counters don't seem to be moving.

Comment: Also here are some observations. When the rst variable is populated I can see the first record in the Fields.Value. When the MoveLast is executed I can see the last record from the query. So the data is there...I just am not sure how to format it to the list like in the original DAO code.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Please check out the answer I posted.