# MSAccess 2007 Select Query RecordSet RecordCount from Excel 2007 VBA always returns 0

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have below `VBA` code to Query `MS Access` database 2007 version by `ADODB` object. The Access database has more than 1 Million rows and 18 columns. The format of all the fields are `Text`.

`RecordSet.RecordCount` returned by `Select` query returns 0 always. (But there are matching rows in Access file).

But `RecordSet.RecordCount` return by `Count(*)` query returns correct count of rows.

My System Specifications:
OS : Windows 7 64 bit
MS Access : MS Access 2007
MS Excel : MS Excel 2007
References for the VBA Project:
Visual Basic For Applications
Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

My Code:

```
Sub GetDonorDataByGiftAmountAndGiftDate()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, GiftDate As String, GiftAmount As String, LastName As String, FirstName As String
LastName = Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row).Value: FirstName = Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value: GiftDate = Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
StrWhereCond = ""
LastNameCond = IIf(LastName = "", "", "DataTable.[LastName] LIKE '*" & LastName & "*'")
StrWhereCond = LastNameCond
FirstNameCond = IIf(StrWhereCond = "", "", " AND ") & IIf(FirstName = "", "", "DataTable.[FirstName] LIKE '*" & FirstName & "*'")
StrWhereCond = StrWhereCond & FirstNameCond
GiftDateCond = IIf(StrWhereCond = "", "", " AND ") & IIf(GiftDate = "", "", "DataTable.[GiftDate] LIKE '*" & GiftDate & "*'")
StrWhereCond = StrWhereCond & GiftDateCond
GiftAmountCond = IIf(StrWhereCond = "", "", " AND ") & IIf(GiftAmount = "", "", "DataTable.[GiftAmount] LIKE '*" & GiftAmount & "*'")
StrWhereCond = StrWhereCond & GiftAmountCond
strsql = "SELECT GiftID FROM DataTable WHERE " & StrWhereCond & ";"

On Error Resume Next
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  MsgBox "Connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
  Exit Sub
End If
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Database for Gifts.accdb;"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  'Error! Release the objects and exit.
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set conn = Nothing
  'Display an error message to the user.
  MsgBox "Recordset was not created!", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
  Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Set thee cursor location.
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
'OPEN RECORDSET
rs.Open strsql, conn
If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
  'Close the recordset and the connection.
  rs.Close
  conn.Close
  'Release the objects.
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set conn = Nothing
  'Enable the screen.
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  'In case of an empty recordset display an error.
  MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"
  Exit Sub
End If

Do While Not rs.EOF
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close

' FREE RESOURCES
Set rs = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Constructed SQL Statement from Debug.Print as asked by [June7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361615/msaccess-2007-select-query-recordset-recordcount-from-excel-2007-vba-always-retu?noredirect=1#comment127837350_72361615).

```
SELECT GiftID FROM DataTable WHERE DataTable.[GiftAmount] LIKE '*100.0000*';
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129543/adodb-recordset-recordcount-always-returns-1

Comment: @RegBes: Tried it. I still get 0.

Comment: Debug.Print the constructed SQL statement - edit question to post it.

Comment: @June7: Added the constructed SQL statement.

Comment: Reference [Comparison of Microsoft Access SQL and ANSI SQL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/comparison-of-microsoft-access-sql-and-ansi-sql-93edf744-9070-4af8-bcf9-1953a87bd6e5)