# Append file names to sql statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following working code that consolidates data from a folder (through filedialog)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, SQL As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        .Columns("A:H").ClearContents
    End With
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:H]"
    ConsolidateData ws, "", SQL, 1
End Sub

Sub ConsolidateData(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal sKeyword As String, ByVal strSql As String, ByVal iColTarget As Long)
    Dim sFolderPath As String, sFileName As String, sProvider As String, bHeadersLoaded As Boolean, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sFolderPath = GetFolderPath()
    If sFolderPath = Empty Then MsgBox "No Folder Selected", vbExclamation: Exit Sub
    sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sKeyword & "*.xlsx")
    Do While sFileName <> ""
        strSql = "SELECT *, '" & Left(sFileName, Len(sFileName) - 5) & "' as [FileName] FROM [Sheet1$A1:H]"
        sProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sFolderPath & sFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        With CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            .Open strSql, sProvider
            If Not bHeadersLoaded And Not .EOF Then
                For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                    ws.Cells(1, iColTarget + i) = .Fields(i).Name
                Next i
                bHeadersLoaded = True
            End If
            ws.Cells(Rows.Count, iColTarget).End(xlUp).Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset .DataSource
            .Close
        End With
ContinueLoop:
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done", 64
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print sFileName: Err.Clear: Resume ContinueLoop
    End If
End Sub

Function GetFolderPath() As String
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fd.InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path
    fd.Title = "Select Folder"
    If fd.Show = -1 Then GetFolderPath = fd.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End Function
```

The code adds extra column at the first column (column A) for the file names. But I need to let this column to be at the end. What should I modify in the code?
The question posted here too
https://eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=39636

Comment: So you are saying in this query, `SELECT *, '" & Left(sFileName, Len(sFileName) - 5) & "' as [FileName] FROM ...`, the `FileName` appears as first column in results? Very interesting with ACE engine!

Comment: Yes, and I need to make the extra column to be at the end of the results after column H (to be in column I)

Comment: Looks like you can't shift the filename to the end via SQL - but you can add it as an extra column after the call to `CopyFromRecordset` - use the recordset's `RecordCount` proprty to set the range to be populated with the filename.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add it via the SQL:

```vb
        '...
        '...
        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        With rs
            .Open strSql, sProvider
            
            If Not bHeadersLoaded And Not .EOF Then
                For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                    ws.Cells(1, iColTarget + i) = .Fields(i).Name
                Next i
                ws.Cells(1, iColTarget + .Fields.Count) = "FileName"
                bHeadersLoaded = True
            End If
            With ws.Cells(Rows.Count, iColTarget).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .CopyFromRecordset rs
                .Offset(0, rs.Fields.Count).Resize(rs.RecordCount).Value = FileBaseName(sFileName)
            End With
            
            .Close
        End With
        '...
        '...
```

`FileBaseName` function:

```
Function FileBaseName(fileName As String) As String
    FileBaseName = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").getbasename(fileName)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got nothing at all in the results.

Comment: Maybe you can expand on that a little? You go no results at all?  You didn't get any filename populated?  Did you step though your code and see where it was going off the rails?

Comment: The nested With means in `.CopyFromRecordset` the `.DataSource` and the `.RecordCount` is not applied to the recordset.

Comment: May also need `RS.CursorLocation = adUseClient` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129543/adodb-recordset-recordcount-always-returns-1/46130089#46130089